# Twig return value from a template?

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

sub.html

```
{% set xx = 10 %}
```

main.html

```
{% set xx = '20' %}
{% include 'sub.html' %}
{{ xx }}
```

Which would give:

```
20
```

Seems variables in a twig template are scoped within that particular template and **not** accessible from outside scope.

Is there any way to make it give **10**?

I ask this because it can be useful to do basic **variable assignments / calculations** inside Twig templates so as to simplify / normalize the parameters we need to provide to Twig_Template::render().

These **variable assignments / calculations** operations are usually shared by multiple Twig templates and it makes sense to group them in one place like a function that can be re-used from multiple templates.

Is there any way to return a value from a macro or an included template? Or make them use outside variables by reference?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. It's not what you want in general, but could be useful.

Base template `base.html.twig`:

```
{% block navbar %}
    {%  if navbar_style is not defined  %}
        {% set navbar_style = 'navbar-inverse navbar-transparent' %}
    {% endif %}
    {% include 'LibraryBundle:BaseComponents:header.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Some page template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% set navbar_style='navbar-ct-blue' %}
...
```

So you can make some decision based on variable in inherited template.